# Grades won't be sent to Gradebook in Google Classroom

Tags: google-classroom

Got the Google Classroom verification approved. Everything is done correctly: class import, roster import, assignment creation, etc. But we cannot send "grades" from our platform to Gradebook. Any help?

When an assignment is assessed in our platform and a grade is given, it should be sent to the Google Classroom Gradebook corresponding assignment COLUMN in draft, but grade is not sent. How can we solve this?